# Can't change the items in list correctly

Tags: python

So im working on a rather simple task. 
I have a list of magicians:

```
magicians_1 = ["Merlin","Harry Potter","Sabrina"]
```

The goal of the function show_magicians is to just print out the name of the magicians:

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician)
```

But my goal is to write a function that changes the name of the magician by adding "the Great" at the end of the name:

```
def make_great(magicians):
   for magician in magicians:
       magician = magician.replace(magician, magician + " the Great")
   return(magician)
```

This is what I've come up with. However if I call the function make_great wit the list magicians_1 and then call show_magicians() with magicians_1 the names stay unchanged.

If I print() magician in make_great() instead of returning it, it prints out the correct names. But that is not the goal of the function. I want to permenantly change the names.

So my question is how can I change the names an print out the correct results by calling show_magicians ?

Comment: The ```return``` statement on the second version of your function ends the ```for``` loop on the last name in the list.

Comment: @accdias That's been fixed in an edit

Comment: OK. I guess you now need to return ```magicians``` and not just ```magician```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using a for...in loop. This means `magician` is a copy of the item at `magicians[i]`. To modify items in an array you need to reference the original array by using an index.

```
def make_great(magicians):
   for i in range(len(magicians)):
       magicians[i] = magicians[i] + " the Great"
   return(magician)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply rebinding your loop variable. You have to actually rebind the list index. E.g.:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for i, magician in enumerate(magicians):
        magicians[i] = magician + " the Great"
```

Apart from the spurious `return` statement, your code is the rough equivalent of the following which makes it more obvious:

```
for i in range(len(magicians)):
    magician = magicians[i]
    magician = something  # why would magicians[i] be affected by this line?
```

Answer (score 0):

You got several issues here:

1. You have a return inside a for loop which means that the function will return the first value
2. The list that you pass will not change since you didn't change its values.
3. I don't think you need replace here, you can just iterate over the list items and add 'the great' to each although I can't find a reason to do so. Just have: `for i in range(len(magicians)): magicians[i] = magicians[i] + ' the Great'`

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered why your original solution was not working.  Here is another example of a viable solution, this one using a list comprehension.

```
def make_great(magicians):
    magicians = [r + ' the Great' for r in magicians]
    return magicians
```